# how to add message generator in ros buildform

Tags: ros, genmsg, jenkins

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I have updated our ros client message generation package (geneus :  https://github.com/k-okada/jsk_roseus/tree/new_geneus/geneu)s, which depends on only python and genmsg.

I'd like to ask add this message generation on ros buildfirm and could you instruct me how to proceed

- should I create a repository that only contains geneus ?
- should I post somthing to somewhere ?

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193612/how-to-add-message-generator-in-ros-buildform/) by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1186 on 2014-09-27

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2014-09-27**:
What is your expectation? To be applied for your message packages depending on it or to be used as a standard generator beside gencpp, genpy and genlisp?

**Comment by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) on 2014-09-28**:
yes, exactory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The default message generators are defined in the `message_generation` package: https://github.com/ros/message_generation/blob/groovy-devel/package.xml

But adding additional generators will require some discussion. Especially since there already is a lisp generator. Please open a ticket similar to https://github.com/ros/message_generation/issues/1 to discuss it there.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2014-09-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1